# TypeError: doc is not a function at addSubCollectionDocument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a new document to a non-existing sub-collection in a document(solutionsCollection/docID/commentsSubCollection).
But I'm getting this error message when I add a document to the sub-collection:

> TypeError: doc is not a function at addSubCollectionDocument

Code to add a new document to a `comments` sub-collection:

```
  const addSubCollectionDocument = async (docID, doc) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })
    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, c, docID)
      const colRef = collection(docRef, "comments")
      const addedDocument = await addDoc(colRef, doc)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ADDED_DOCUMENT", payload: addedDocument })
      return addedDocument
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error })
      return null
    }
  }
```

handleSubmit function:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const commentToAdd = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        content: newComment.trim(),
        reactions: [],
        user: {
          userID: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        },
        replies: [],
        createdAt: new Date(),
      }
      await addSubCollectionDocument(id, commentToAdd)
      setNewComment("")
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

useFirestore hook code:

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react"
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  serverTimestamp,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useFirestore = (c) => {
  const [response, dispatch] = useReducer(firestoreReducer, initialState)
  const [isCancelled, setIsCancelled] = useState(false)

  // only dispatch is not cancelled
  const dispatchIfNotCancelled = (action) => {
    if (!isCancelled) {
      dispatch(action)
    }
  }

  // add a document
  const addDocument = async (doc) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })

    try {
      const createdAt = serverTimestamp()
      const addedDocument = await addDoc(collection(db, c), {
        ...doc,
        createdAt,
      })
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ADDED_DOCUMENT", payload: addedDocument })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: err.message })
    }
  }

  // Add document to sub collection
  const addSubCollectionDocument = async (docID, doc) => {
    dispatch({ type: "IS_PENDING" })
    try {
      const docRef = doc(db, c, docID)
      const colRef = collection(docRef, "comments")
      const addedDocument = await addDoc(colRef, doc)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ADDED_DOCUMENT", payload: addedDocument })
      return addedDocument
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatchIfNotCancelled({ type: "ERROR", payload: error })
      return null
    }
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setIsCancelled(true)
  }, [])

  return {
    addDocument,
    addSubCollectionDocument,
    response,
  }
}
```

File where I'm importing `addSubCollectionDocument` hook:

```
import { useFirestore } from "../../hooks/useFirestore"
import { useAuthContext } from "../../hooks/useAuthContext"

const SolutionComments = ({ solution }) => {
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("")
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  const { id } = useParams()
  const { addSubCollectionDocument, response } = useFirestore("solutions")

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      const commentToAdd = {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
        content: newComment.trim(),
        reactions: [],
        user: {
          userID: user.uid,
          avatarURL: user.photoURL,
          displayName: user.displayName,
          username: user.reloadUserInfo.screenName,
        },
        replies: [],
        createdAt: new Date(),
      }
      await addSubCollectionDocument(id, commentToAdd)
      setNewComment("")
      if (response) {
        console.log(response.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (...)}
```

Package.json gist:
https://gist.github.com/rishipurwar1/57fbf348cd9755a940e7e3f218de570f

Firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /challenges/{challenge}{
        allow read: if true
    }
    match /resources/{resource}{
        allow read: if true
    }
    match /solutions/{solution}{
      allow read: if true
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userID;
    }
    match /users/{userId}{
        allow create: if true
      allow read: if true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can see how you are importing those functions and also include your package.json.

Comment: @Dharmaraj just added a code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const addSubCollectionDocument = async (docID, doc) => { ... })
// That "doc" parameter is not a function      ^^^
```

That parameter seems to be an object that you are passing to `addSubCollectionDocument()`. Try renaming that to something else like:

```
const addSubCollectionDocument = async (docID, docData) => {
  const colRef = collection(db, c, docID, "comments")
  const addedDocument = await addDoc(colRef, doc)
})
```

---

You haven't specified security rules for your comments sub-collection. Try adding the following rules:

```
match /c/{docId}/comments/{commentId} {
  allow read, write: if true; 
}
```

Do update the `if true` to required rules as per your use case.

Comment: Now! I'm getting this error message when I submit a new comment: `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: Do I need a permission to create a sub-collection on a particular document?

Comment: added firebase rules to the question

Comment: Thanks Dharmaraj, I updated the firebase rules and now it's working fine! Thanks again for your help

Comment: @r007 I've updated my answer. Also I don't know what value of `"c"` is in `doc(db, c, id)`. So do update value of c in security rules

Comment: I have a doubt related to the firebase subcollection: let's say I have 100 documents in a subcollection `comments`, so if someone visits a solution page and it would increase reads by 100, or it just read the parent document of that sub-collection as one read

Comment: @r007 every document fetch costs 1 read. So if you are querying all those 100 comments then you'll be charged 100 reads. It's just a nested collection at the end. You should paginate the queries