# Issue with Firestore doc function inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a project that involves moving data from one Firestore collection to another using JavaScript and the Firebase SDK. I've encountered an issue when trying to use the doc function inside a forEach loop.

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
// Import necessary Firebase libraries and initialize Firebase app

async function moveData() {
const db = getFirestore(app);
const sourceCollectionRef = collection(db, 'sourceCollection');
const targetCollectionRef = collection(db, 'targetCollection');

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(sourceCollectionRef);

querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) =\> {
const docId = doc.id;
const targetDocRef = doc(targetCollectionRef, docId); // This line doesn't work

    // Some logic to manipulate data
    
    // Attempt to set data to targetDocRef
    await setDoc(targetDocRef, /* modified data */);

});
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the doc function doesn't seem to work inside the forEach loop. I'm receiving an error saying that doc is not a function.

I've tried various approaches, including defining targetDocRef outside of the loop and passing docId as a parameter to it, but I still face the same issue.

What I Tried:

1. Inside the forEach loop, I attempted to use the doc function to create a reference to a document in Firestore's target collection.
2. I passed the targetCollectionRef and the docId as arguments to the doc function, expecting it to return a reference to the target document.
3. I then attempted to use setDoc to set data to the target document.

I was expecting that this code would create a reference to the target document for each document in the source collection and allow me to set data to the target documents.

However, I encountered an issue where the doc function inside the forEach loop was not recognized, and I received an error saying that doc is not a function.

I'm looking for an alternative solution or insights on how to correctly reference documents inside a loop in Firestore using JavaScript and the Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is what you have two definitions of `doc`:

1. The top-level `doc` function that you import from the Firestore SDK.
2. The `doc` variable that you declare here: `querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) =\> {`

That variable hides the `doc` function, which explains why you can't call the `doc` function anymore inside the callback.

The solution is to use a different name for the variable:

```
querySnapshot.forEach(async (snapshot) => {
  const docId = snapshot.id;
  const targetDocRef = doc(targetCollectionRef, docId);

  ...
});
```

Also see:

- [doc is not a function error on deleting document in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74699804/doc-is-not-a-function-error-on-deleting-document-in-firebase)
- [TypeError: doc is not a function at addSubCollectionDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72149531/typeerror-doc-is-not-a-function-at-addsubcollectiondocument)
- [Why I receive "TypeError: doc is not a function" (Firebase 9, Firestore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817695/why-i-receive-typeerror-doc-is-not-a-function-firebase-9-firestore/74817905#74817905)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your explanation about the two definitions of doc and how the variable declaration was causing the issue makes perfect sense. Renaming the variable inside the forEach loop to snapshot indeed resolved the problem